# my code works but not exactly as i expect it to

Tags: python-3.x, logic, text-to-speech

I'm new to all this coding thing and I was writing a program to convert text-to-speech. I have written it and it does work but not as i expected it to work.

### Code :

```
from gtts import gTTS

import time

from pygame import mixer

a = input("Enter shoutout names separated by a comma: ")

a.split(",")

list = []

for i in a:

    list.append(a)

for i in list:

    g = gTTS("Shoutout to "+i,lang="en",tld="com.au")

    speech_file = 'spf.mp3'

    g.save(speech_file)

    mixer.init()

    mixer.music.load('spf.mp3')

    mixer.music.play()

    time.sleep(len(list))
```

It's python. Say the input was a, b, c and d. Now the following is the output:
Shoutout to a, b, c, and d(in computer voice).
I was expecting:
Shoutout to a
Shoutout to b
Shoutout to c
Shoutout to d`

Can someone smarter than me tell me why that is not happening.

Comment: FYI, While everyone is new to programming at some point you should be able to write a decent subject line for your problem. The subject line "my code works but not exactly as i expect it to" is one of the worst I've read this week. Learning to add debugging print statements at strategic points in your code to verify that variables have the expected values is a technique you should learn to employ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, there are lots of mistakes. Here is the thing... The [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) function returns a list. So, you need to put it in a variable.
Suppose `a = a,b,c,d`. When you loop through `a`, you're looping through a string like:

```
a = a,b,c,d 
[0] = a
[1] = b
[2] = c
[3] = d
```

You're also appending `a` to `list` not looping through the items. So the list in the end is `list = ['a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d']`.

So, In the last loop `g = 'a,b,c,d'`.

Wrapping up, I believe it would be something like this:

```
from gtts import gTTS

import time

from pygame import mixer

a = input("Enter shoutout names separated by a comma: ")

a_list = a.split(",")

complete_text = ""
for item in a_list:
    complete_text += f"Shoutout to {item} "

g = gTTS(complete_text, lang="en", tld="com.au")
speech_file = 'spf.mp3'
g.save(speech_file)
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('spf.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(len(a_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.split(',')` does not modify `a` in-place. You want `a = a.split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

Split has to be assigned to variable/names as it return a new list. Just split the input then iterate over it:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import time
from pygame import mixer

a = input("Enter shoutout names separated by a comma: ").split(',')

for i in a:
    g = gTTS("Shoutout to "+i,lang="en",tld="com.au")
    speech_file = 'spf.mp3'
    g.save(speech_file)
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(speech_file)
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(len(a))
    mixer.music.unload()
```